# Загрузка полностью разных данных(картинки) в recycler-view одного фрагмента

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, recyclerview

У меня есть фрагмент с двумя кнопками. Каждая из них сейчас ведет на фрагмент с recycler-view, однако надо сделать так, чтобы в recycler-view загружались полностью разные картинки в зависимости от выбранной кнопки (например, при переходе по кнопке 1 в recycler-view должны загружаться картинки по первой теме, при переходе по 2 кнопке загружались картинки по второй теме. Можно ли это сделать с один фрагментом с recycler-view? Или нужно создавать второй для второй кнопки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас есть два варианта решения вашей проблемы - создавать для каждой кнопки свой фрагмент (это на мой не очень правильное решение) либо сделать при переходе на фрагмент отправку переменной которая будет отвечать за определенную кнопку, и дальше при старте фрагмента чистить recyclerView от данных, уведомлять адаптер и загружать данные согласно пришедшей переменной. Вот как вы можете передать переменную в фрагмент:

```
Your_fragment your_fragment = new Your_fragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("название", 0);
your_fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

и дальше вы фильтруете полученную переменную:

```
 Bundle bundle = getArguments();
if (bundle != null) {
type = bundle.getInt("название");
}
```

после получения переменной вы смотрите что пришло, например через switch или if. И дальше при обнаружении определенного идентификатора вы чистите список и заполняете его нужными данными. Есть два варианта чистки списка - создание полностью нового фрагмента, либо при получении переменной можно вызывать функцию чистки. Вот пример функции для чистки с моего проекта:

```
public void clearData() {
    myList.clear();
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Если возникнут сложности - не стесняйтесь и спрашивайте, постараемся помочь. Удачи :)

Comment: а если нужно, чтобы картинки кэшировались, то есть без интернета должны быть доступны картинки и по первой теме, и по второй?

Comment: загружаете картинки предварительно, и дальше при запуске приложения делаете проверку на наличие интернета, если его нет, то тянуть картинки из кэша, если есть то загружать и не парится

Comment: А bundle прописывать в onClick кнопки? Если да, но выдает ошибку Non-static method 'setArguments(android.os.Bundle)' cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: а что именно вы прописываете в метод клика по кнопке? возможно где-то ошибка

Comment: TestFragment newFragment = new TestFragment();
                ((AppCompatActivity) imageView.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.content_frame, newFragment)
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("DataOne", 0);
                TestFragment.setArguments(bundle);

Comment: нужно сначала объявить бандл, впихнуть туда данные, приписать бандл свежему фрагменту а потом уже делать транзакцию

Comment: Тогда мне нужно передавать метод mRef = database.getReference("DataOne"), Получается два boundle прописываем в фрагменте с кнопками, а как их вызвать в фрагменте с RecyclerView?